# How to reset css class

Tags: css

On my style.css I have this CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline:none;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I use it on most of my pages, I want to cancel it on a specific page, how can I achieve this without removing the whole CSS file?
I have tried unset but it doesn't work, also tried to remove for a specific element but is still not working

```
ul, li:not(.editor) {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
```

The main reason for this is that editor(ckeditor 5) doesn't display lists, and list style, also padding and margin are affecting space between rows
[not looking good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK6VR.png)
[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x0gE.png)

Update:
From how I have it on style.css on my index.php I want to for the whole page or for the editor(best option) like this:

```
* {
}

ul, li {
}
```

I want that lists and style list to just behave normal, right now they are removed because of that CSS from my style.css

Comment: why don't you try the inverse approach? you keep those general rules and add a new rule for children of the editor only (.editor) that will override those css attributes with what you expect. Something like `.editor ul, .editor li{ list-style-type: disc;}` for example. Is that what you meant? By the way in those 2 pictures I see differences going beyond what you said

Comment: I want them to do nothing on my current page( empty if possible) because they destroy format of lists, ul li {   }

Comment: Do you want to not apply those rules on a specific page?

Comment: @Alexandru unfortunately your question becomes more and more unclear every word you add to it. I tried a suggestion but didn't receive a comment. Anyway at this point if you want to reset those rules in the easiest (and most wrong) way possible you can just add a css set of rules that will carbon copy those selectors redefining the values of all those css properties using `!important`

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure it out without removing the whole CSS file

Comment: I didn't say remove.. I said add. Why do you need to remove the whole css file? can't you just add even a style element to your html?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I said that i want to remove it for a specific page, if possible for the editor, both methods are good, but for the moment everything I tried it keeps the CSS style

Comment: I'm updating my question maybe this helps out

Answer (score 1):

In the specific page give the body a special class like this

`<body class="unstyle">`

then on your css file reset the style

```
.unstyle ul, .unstyle li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: those selectors will select also lists being inside the editor. I don't see how it solves the problem