# Is There A Way To Limit The Scope Of HTML Entered Into CKEditor?

Tags: html, ckeditor5, inline-styles

My company runs a web application and in a couple of places our clients have a text editor (CKeditor) into which they can enter text for display on the customer facing area of the app. The information has to be displayed in very specific ways due to the way the products are regulated, and the client often copy/pastes html with inline style rules that they get from directly from their suppliers.

A couple of times now, we've had issues come up where the inline style rules aren't assigned to classes or anything, so they affect other parts of the page. We can go in and manually fix the code, but it absorbs a bunch of time, and we run the risk of adjusting something and taking a product out of compliance, if we fix it we take on some liability.

1. We can't have the client be responsible for fixing it, as they have no clue what they're looking at, they literally paste it from the supplier.
2. We can make it so that the areas of the customer portal with content from the CKeditor open in a new tab instead of being displayed  on the same page, and then the style rules wouldn't touch anything that they're not supposed to. This is the solution I'm considering right now, but it'll take a fair amount of time and will require the client to communicate the change to all of their customers; again, pretty strict regulations.

My question: Is there some way we can just put a container around any content entered into CKeditor, so it only affects a limited area on the display page? Something that will basically limit the scope of inline style rules, but that we can create outside of the ckeditor?

Thank you!

Apologies for any faulty terminology or vagueness, I'm new to the field and faking it as best I can currently :)

Comment: Asking the same question didn't need a new user. Now I see how it earned 3 upvotes before. Inline styles are styles defined as an attribute of the html element... I'm quite sure you meant something else. Maybe the easiest way to achieve exactly what you are looking for could be to rely on the fact that css is scoped within a document and that an iframe would be out of its scope. You could try to put the editor inside the iframe then. Otherwise there's no way you can interrupt css rules already existing.

Comment: "Asking the same question didn't need a new user. Now I see how it earned 3 upvotes before" 

Haven't asked this question before! If there's a similar question can you link it so I can review?

"I'm quite sure you meant something else."

Very possible, we have validations in place preventing client from linking to external style sheets, but there are rules in the html like: 

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

This one isn't scoped so it affected a bunch of tables it shouldn't have. Putting the CKeditor content in an iframe would solve this?

Comment: I apologize for my terrible comment. The reason pushing me to say those things and make lots of invalid assumptions was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73221816/how-to-reset-css-class#comment129316895_73221816) a question almost identical few minutes before (with the intentions: Limit Scope Of CSS outside CKEditor) where the author after several suggestions couldn't still follow the hints given. The author also said he was going to change the question and suddendly yours appeared. This question had the same exact nature and I went straight with false accusation. I apologize again.

Comment: By the way the iframe solution I gave was just a one shot to try if it could catch the problem. You may try it putting the ckeditor inside an iframe and see if the outside css rules will not affect its style. Unfortunately there's no much more help I can give beyond that.